# Setting separate data binding for controls in User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am relatively new to WPF and I am attempting to design my first project using MVVM pattern.

Now I have the main window as my view.I have an user control on this.Now the user control has 2 expanders and each need to pull it's own data.

```
  <Expander Header="Electrical Components" Name="EC"
                  IsExpanded="True">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElecViewModel.ToolBoxItems }">
                ............
     <Expander Header="Structural Components" Name="SC"
                  IsExpanded="True">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StructViewModel.ToolBoxItemsS}">
                .............
```

So I created 2 view models with the idea that I can do a data bind for each of the expanders. The idea is to pull some images under each expander. 
First expander I attach to this view model

```
public class ElecViewModel
{
    private List<ToolBoxData> toolBoxItems = new List<ToolBoxData>();
    public ElecViewModel()
    {           
        toolBoxItems.Add(new ToolBoxData("../Images/Inverter.jpg", typeof(InverterDesignerItemViewModel)));          
        toolBoxItems.Add(new ToolBoxData("../Images/Recombiner.jpg", typeof(RecombinerDesignerItemViewModel)));
    }
    public List<ToolBoxData> ToolBoxItems
    {
        get { return toolBoxItems; }
    }
  }
```

..And second one to this view model

```
public class StructViewModel
{
    private List<ToolBoxData> toolBoxItemsS = new List<ToolBoxData>();

    public StructViewModel()
    {

        toolBoxItemsS.Add(new ToolBoxData("../Images/SafetySwitch.jpg", typeof(SafetySwitchDesignerItemViewModel)));         
        toolBoxItemsS.Add(new ToolBoxData("../Images/ScadaPanel.jpg", typeof(ScadaDesignerItemViewModel)));
    }

    public List<ToolBoxData> ToolBoxItemsS
    {
        get { return toolBoxItemsS; }
    }
}
```

Now my first expander is getting loaded with the correct images.whereas the second one doesn't. The public list of the second view model does not get hit even though I have binded to it like the first list ? Is there an obvious reason for that ?I tried setting the binding source of second expander to first list and it gets populated suggesting the list I am creating for second one has some issue in getting binded to a control. Please suggest as i am not able to identify any obvious issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition don't set the `DataContext` of your `usercontrol` explicitly. Assuming your `MainViewModel` has two properties for ViewModel instances `ElecViewModel` and `StructViewModel`. And `MainViewModel` is `DataContext` of your `Window`, you can bind these expanders like

```
<Expander Header="Electrical Components" Name="EC"
                  IsExpanded="True">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElecViewModel.ECData}">
            ............
<Expander Header="Structural Components" Name="SC"
                  IsExpanded="True">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StructViewModel.SCData}">
            .............
```

Comment: This did it. I was doing some typo errors on the xaml.